# get ride of Recursion Error in large number of iteration and access to element of joint of 2 lists iteratively python

Tags: python, list, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I need to do iteratively (about 3 millions times) `X=[X B]` which `B=[b1,b2,b3,b4,b5]` and save this in a file to access in future.

I encounter two problems:

1- The first problem is that the size of `X` is `size=(2,)` and I do not know how to access different element (i.e. `b1..b5` of each time) because all of them are supposed to be element number zero of each time!
For solving this problem I have tried to use `X.append(B)` but I saw an error. I have tried to use `X.append(B[0])...X.append(B[4])` but the problem was not solved! How I can do this?

2- The second one is that I use `np.save('Xsaved.npy',X)` but when I see

```
    `np.save('Xsaved.npy',X)
File "C:\Users\L\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 509, in save
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\L\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 576, in write_array
    pickle.dump(array, fp, protocol=2, **pickle_kwargs)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object
```

when Time is more than `450`! however I need to iterate it for about 2.5 millions time.
I would like to know how I could solve these two problems!

p.s. I write a pseudo code to see what I have done!

```
episodes=40000
T=3000000
for e in range(episodes):

    REWARDALLkol.append(REWARDALL)
    REWARDALL=[]

    X=[]

    for time_t in range(1,T+1):

        B= functioncalculatedB() #B=[b0,b1,b2,b3,b4]
        X=[X, B]

np.save('./save/X.npy',X)
```

Comment: It sounds like you've made a data structure nested 3 million levels deep. Is that what you intended?

Comment: I have written a pseudo code for what I have done! I need to access to elements of X ! Also, I should save this in a file!

Comment: np.save is meant for saving numpy arrays.  It can save list by first making an array, and using pickle on objects.