# calculating, saving and accessing a list of list in a npy file python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, recursion, nested-lists

This is somehow related to my post [get ride of Recursion Error in large number of iteration and access to element of joint of 2 lists iteratively python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201747/get-ride-of-recursion-error-in-large-number-of-iteration-and-access-to-element-o)

I have 2 more questions:

1-How I can write a code to access to `[3,3]` in list `X=[[[[[],[1,1]],[2,2]],[3,3]],[4,4]]`
because as I check the size it is `(2,)` all of them are considered as element `0`? and how I can change it to

2-How I can get rid of recursion error of the following code when T is big number?

```
import numpy as np
import random

def functioncalculatedB():
    return([(random.randint(1,2)),(random.randint(1,3)),(random.randint(1,4)),(random.randint(1,5)),random.randint(1,6)])

def main():
    '''X=[[[[[],1],2],3],4]

    print(np.shape(X))
    '''
    episodes=40000
    T=2000000
    for e in range(episodes):
        X=[]

        for time_t in range(1,T+1):

            B= functioncalculatedB() #B=[b0,b1,b2,b3,b4]
            X=[X, B] #X.extend(B)

    np.save('./save/X.npy',X)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `X` is not an array, it is a list. Lists and arrays are different objects.

Comment: That's a deeply nested list. `X[0][0][0][0]` is `[]`if I've counted right.  `X[0][1]` is `[3,3]`.  I' m not surprised that kind of nesting would produce a recursion error.

Comment: python is the wrong language for this kind of data structure.

Comment: you have put a size 2 list inside a size 2 recursively.

Comment: Normally in python we append new values to the end of an existing list.  We can access the first with `[0]`, and the last with [-1].  Second to the last with [-2] etc.  This a simple flat list.  It's easy to iterate through such a list.  And to turn it into a numpy array for calculations.

Comment: what is your suggested solution for get rid of this nested loop and joint two list in millions of time!

Comment: Thanks but I have written in my topic list in a list!